# Delete single Char in String java

Tags: java, string, char, position

I have an array of String, and the items are like : 02:11, 11:12..
I want to delete the 0 in first position.

```
if (orari[i].substring(0,0) == "0") {
   orari[i] = orari[i].substring(1,4);
}
```

It doesn't work, why?

Comment: `==` does not suitable to compare strings

Comment: do like below:

    if (orari[i].charAt(0) == '0') {
       orari[i] = orari[i].substring(1);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `substring` bounds are faulty. `0, 0` means 0 length string. That will not get you first character. You should use `0, 1`. And then use `equals()` method for String comparison:

```
if (orari[i].substring(0,1).equals("0"))
```

Also, you can avoid that `substring` in `if` condition by using `charAt()` method:

```
if (orari[i].charAt(0) == '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it should be like this:

```
if (orari[i].charAt(0) == '0') {
   orari[i] = orari[i].substring(1,4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (orari[i].substring(0,0).equals("0")) {
   orari[i] = orari[i].substring(1,4);
}
```

use `equals()` to compare string, not ==